# Javascript Fade Text In & Out - Different Times

Tags: javascript

I've been using this code to fade text in and out. I am using it for a news ticker  Occasionally though, some headlines will be much longer than others and will require more time for a user to read. Is there a way to set a different time for each fade?

```
 <script>
    var counter = 0;

    function changeText()
    {
    var quotes = new Array();

    quotes[0] = "quote1";
    quotes[1] = "quote2";
    quotes[2] = "quote3";
    quotes[3] = "quote4";
    quotes[4] = "quote5";

    if (counter > 4)
        {
        counter = 0;
        }

    document.getElementById("textslide").innerHTML = quotes[counter];

    setTimeout(function(){changeText()},1000);
    counter ++;
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: _“will require more time for a user to read”_ – since you can’t possibly know how fast (or slow) readers your users are, this is a bad idea _in general_ from a usability point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8P9m/2/)):

```
var counter = 0;

function changeText()
{
    // Use an array of objects so each quote can have it's own display duration
    var quotes = new Array();
    quotes[0] = { text: "quote1", time: 500 };
    quotes[1] = { text: "quote2", time: 500 };
    quotes[2] = { text: "quote3", time: 500 };
    quotes[3] = { text: "quote4", time: 500 };
    quotes[4] = { text: "much longer quote", time: 2000 };

    // get the current quote
    var quote = quotes[counter];

    document.getElementById("textslide").innerHTML = quote.text;

    setTimeout(function(){changeText()}, quote.time);
    counter ++;

    // You probably want to reset your counter here
    if (counter > 4) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```